# VLOOKUP not working in excel sheet

Tags: excel

Have two sheet in EXCEL workbook,

Sheet1:

```
    A                         B
  Customer Number       CUSTCLAS
    81417
    80352
    90353
    91857
    107144
    115059
    119199
    189802
    100124
    277612
```

Sheet2

```
A              B      
CUSTCLAS      Role
45163     EC INDIVIDUALS
80352     EC INDIVIDUALS
81417     EC INDIVIDUALS
90353     EC INDIVIDUALS
91857     EC INDIVIDUALS
100124    EC INDIVIDUALS
107144    EC INDIVIDUALS
115059    EC INDIVIDUALS
119199    EC INDIVIDUALS
189802    EC INDIVIDUALS
267552    EC INDIVIDUALS
277612    EC University
288097    EC INDIVIDUALS
296887    EC INDIVIDUALS
299033    EC INDIVIDUALS
353409        EC INDIVIDUAL
```

I have to compare Sheet1-A values to Sheet2-A and corresponding Sheet2-B values need to show in Sheet1-B column.

I have tried this "VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)`" in sheet1-B1 but not working, Can anyone help me for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you replicate the setup in google docs?

Comment: THe second argument needs to be `Sheet2!A:B` otherwise the formula only looking at column A, and the third argument needs to be `2` to return the value from column B (the second column in the range `A:B`). See Jerry's answer below. It is correct.

Comment: Tried but not working, its showing me "#N/A" in Sheet1-B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title mentions `VLOOKUP` but you are using `LOOKUP`?

And since you need to return the values in column B of sheet 2, you can use this instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: I have to return values of COLUMN B of Sheet2 to Sheet1-B as per VLOOKUP comparison

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar Okay, I just saw that you edited your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Enter something like

```
=LOOKUP(A2,[Book1]Sheet2!$A$2:$A$17,[Book1]Sheet2!$B$2:$B$17)
```

in [Book1]Sheet1!B2, and copy it until the end of data.

Comment: It's a bit strange.  I tested it in Excel 2007.  Are you sure you don't have spaces or other foreign data in the cells?